# Will my bank interrogate me about source of funds for a large wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, banking

In the UK banks routinely demand from their customers detailed statements about "source of funds" if the customer makes a large deposit (over $100,000). Here is an example:

https://retiready.co.uk/public/support/faq/understanding-our-products/retiready-pension/where-you-money-has-come-from.html

> Will I face this same kind of interrogation in the United States if a large amount is **wired** into my account?

Please note that this is **not** a question about making a large *cash* deposit (which has been discussed, for example, in *[Would depositing large cash amounts cause problems](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/14954/5760))* but about **wire transfer** of a large amount.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/73926/for-a-large-cash-deposit-do-you-have-to-answer-where-it-came-from

Comment: @user209436 I see the similarities between the question OP asked and the question you linked to, but the latter doesn't seem to have a good answer

Comment: @user209436 Not only does the answer to the question you linked to not seem to be very satisfactory, but that _answer_ was posted by Five Bagger who is asking the question here!

Comment: @DilipSarwate That question was about CASH deposits. This is about a wire or bank-to-bank transfer. Big difference.

Comment: Yes indeed, and I have edited your question and its title to make this very clear.

Comment: Large transactions are automatically reported to the government, as are apparent attempts to "structure" a series of payments to avoid that reporting. So the bank not questioning you immediately doesn't mean Los Federales will not appear on your doorstep demanding answers. If you are contemplating something illegal, don't.

Answer (score 2):

I recently received a wire of more than $150K into one of my accounts. (Both sender and receiver accounts are US banking institutions.) My bank never contacted me to ask any questions. However, on my statement I noticed a charge called "Analysis Service Charge". I called the bank to ask them about this charge and was informed it was due to internal analysis for the wire transfer. They did this behind the scenes without needing to contact me. I can only assume that their "analysis" did not turn up anything suspicious, and if it had, perhaps they would have contacted me.

I wouldn't worry about it even if you do receive a phone call and they ask a few questions. I'd advise to be completely honest; if you aren't doing anything wrong, you shouldn't have anything to worry about. Most likely they'd be calling you just to make sure you actually know about it and were expecting the money.

Comment: If their analysis turned up something suspicious the bank would **not** be contacting you. "Unauthorized disclosure of a SAR filing is a federal criminal offense." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspicious_activity_report#Confidentiality

Comment: @ShannonSeverance - Perhaps that is true if they already decided to file a SAR prior to speaking to me. I can imagine a scenario where they aren't sure, and contact me to ask for more info, and depending on my answer they may choose to file a SAR. Perhaps they say, "Great. Just wanted to make sure you knew about it. Have a great day!" and then they go file the SAR. I'm just guessing though- I have no idea what the actual protocol is.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely all wire transfer above a significant amount would be flagged as a suspicious transaction. Nevertheless, as long you provide the Final beneficiary information (name and account number), the bank will process the remittance.

Comment: Is "flagged" a synonym for "interrogated"?

Comment: @DJohnM "Flagged" first means "marked". If the bank officer whose duty is the examination of the transaction chooses to interrogate you, they will do. Interrogation is one step in the process triggered by the flag.

Answer (score -1):

I won't think so. Too much trouble for the compliance and internal audit team. Unless you are moving money from Russia, Iran or those non-FATCA countries.

Comment: You can *edit* your original answer to expand upon it.